# Multiprocessing with Python 3.X ( image processing and numpy )

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm starting a new project to learn python and have some fun. I have unfortunately some issues with sharing resources between different process.

Here a quick presentation of the project: I'm using libraries for image processing ( PIL for python 3.X ), OpenCV and Numpy ( seems to be use on most of the python project).

The Aim of the project is to acquire images with Pillow then sending them to OpenCV for some processing. The particularity is that both process are running simultaneously during a certain amount of time.

I have done some researches about Numpy which brings me to the conclusion that Numpy is perfectly suitable for multiprocessing and it's also compatible with both libraries.
I have seen different methods to achieve such task on the official web site but i don't know which one is the best option.
I obtain images from Pillow which are convert in to numpy's table , i want to send theses numpy tables to OpenCV but the behaviour of the tables aren't similar as what i saw on the official web site.

I thing that the multiprocessing is the best option for what i want to do but maybe I'm wrong and the multi threading is more suitable despite the GIL.
I'm looking for a efficient and powerful solution :) .

Any Help, Advice, Examples will be highly appreciated :).

Comment: This question is really hard to answer as is, because there are no concrete examples or code, nor any sentences ending with question marks :-). What do you mean when you say "the behavior of the tables aren't similar as what i saw on the official web site"?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that wasn't really clear. Here is some code I wrote as a basis. I try to run it properly without sucess: if you have some clue to solve it ?

```
def processscreen(queuescreen):
    # add while later
    process = ScreenManager()                            # my pillow class
    listscreen = process.capture()                       # numpy.array 900 * 600
    queuescreen.put(540000, np.reshape(listscreen, -1))  # just a try


def processinformations(queuescreen):
    # add while later
    process = InformationManager()                       # my opencv class
    # don't know if try catch is useful here just one thing i add during my try
    try:
        process.screen_array = queuescreen.get()
    except Exception as err:
        # just a print
        settings.out(settings.ERROR, settings.ERROR, 'processinformations get listscreen : ' + str(err))
    # after here some work with InformationManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queuescreen = Queue()
    s = multiprocessing.Process(target=processscreen, args=(queuescreen,))
    i = multiprocessing.Process(target=processinformations, args=(queuescreen,))

    i.start()
    s.start()

    i.join()
    s.join()
```